# ¿Cómo puedo recibir un array como parámetro en una función kotlin?

Tags: array, string, kotlin

¿Cómo puedo crear una función que reciba como parámetro un array de String en kotlin?

¿Cómo puedo enviar un array de String como parámetro desde mi método main a una función que se encuentra en otra clase en kotlin?

He realizado la operación para `int`, `long`, y `char`, ya que kotlin me da las lineas de comando: `intArrayOf`, `longArrayOf`, `charArrayOf`, pero no me presenta lo mismo para `String`

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
        var instancia: miPrimerProyectoKotlin = miPrimerProyectoKotlin()`


        val letras: CharArray = charArrayOf('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g')
        val numeros: IntArray = intArrayOf(4, 5, 6, 7, 3, 4)
        val tipolong: LongArray = longArrayOf(123, 456, 789)

        instancia.recibirletras(letras)
        instancia.recibirnumeros(numeros)
        instancia.recibirlong(tipolong)

    }
```

En este momento las funciones solo recorren el array y muestran el contenido en cada posición.

Esta sería mi clase a la que le he creado la instancia:

```
class miPrimerProyectoKotlin() {

    fun recibirletras(miPrimerArray:CharArray):Unit
    {
        var i=0
        for (i in miPrimerArray.indices)
        {
            println(miPrimerArray[i])
        }
    }
    fun recibirnumeros(miPrimerArray:IntArray):Unit
    {

        for (i in miPrimerArray.indices)
        {
            println(miPrimerArray[i])
        }
    }
    fun recibirlong(miPrimerArray:LongArray):Unit
    {

        for (i in miPrimerArray.indices)
        {
            println(miPrimerArray[i])
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Puedes mostrar tu método main.

Comment: @banana_potato_nah agregué una respuesta, espero te sea de utilidad.

Answer (score 2):

**Array de tipo String**

```
val frutas = arrayOf<String>("mango", "pera", "manzana", "uva")
```

**Funcion**

```
fun recibirFrutas(miPrimerArray: Array<String>):Unit
{
    var i=0
    for (i in miPrimerArray.indices)
    {
        println(miPrimerArray[i])
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Definiendo los arrays :

```
    val letras:CharArray= charArrayOf('a','b','c','d','e','f','g')
    val numeros:IntArray= intArrayOf(4,5,6,7,3,4)
    val tipolong:LongArray= longArrayOf(123,456,789)
```

puedes crear los métodos de la clase instancia, que reciban los valores:

```
instancia.recibirletras(letras)
instancia.recibirnumeros(numeros)
instancia.recibirlong(tipolong)
```

Los métodos serían:

---

> ¿como puedo crear una función que reciba como parámetro un array de
>   String en kotlin?

```
   fun recibirletras (letras: CharArray){
        for(i in letras)
            println(i)
    }
```

Que tendría como salida:

```
a
b
c
d
e
f
g
```

---

```
    fun recibirnumeros (numeros: IntArray){
        for(i in numeros)
            println(i)
    }
```

Que tendría como salida:

```
4
5
6
7
3
4
```

---

```
    fun recibirlong (tipolong: LongArray){
        for(i in tipolong)
            println(i)
    }
```

Que tendría como salida:

```
123
456
789
```

---

---

---

En cuanto a tu pregunta:

> ¿como puedo enviar un array de String como parámetro desde mi método
>   main a una función que se encuentra en otra clase en kotlin?

Si la otra clase se encuentra dentro del mismo paquete que Main, solo debes instanciar y llamar los métodos:

```
   var instancia:OtraClase = OtraClase()

    instancia.recibirletras(letras)
    instancia.recibirnumeros(numeros)
    instancia.recibirlong(tipolong)
```

Si la clase se encuentra en otro paquete realizas lo mismo pero en este caso tienes que agregar el import necesario definiendo el paquete donde se encuentra la clase:

```
import <paquete>.OtraClase
...
...
       var instancia:OtraClase = OtraClase()

        instancia.recibirletras(letras)
        instancia.recibirnumeros(numeros)
        instancia.recibirlong(tipolong)
```